# Installing iCloud on XP PC

Tags: icloud

I'm trying to install iCloud on my Windows XP Pro (SP3) PC. Officially it's supported only for Vista and later, but this hack is widely claimed to work:

1. Open iCloudSetup.exe file and unzip its files including
2. Navigate to and open the iCloud.msi with Orca.
3. In the left table select LaunchCondition. Then change in the right table “VersionNT> = 600” to “VersionNT> = 200” and Save.
4. Run modified iCloud.msi and install.
5. Run iCloud Control Panel, located in the Windows Control Panel, and set up as you want.

I tried that promising solution in vain. It seemed to successfully install iCloud, but whenever I try to run it I get 
[this obscure error](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4019461/iCloud-CP-Problem-1.jpg)

After much fruitless searching I've not found out how to proceed from there and would appreciate advice please.

Comment: Pls. only ask questions related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

That trick worked with only the firs versions of iCloud Panel, the v1.0.

For the v2.1 doing the trick the installer ran ok, but when trying to run the iCloud Panel it showed the error you're refering to.

I had some computers running with that older version without any problem.

Try downloading the v1.0 version here:
http://icloud-control-panel-for-windows.uptodown.com/descargar/22412

If you want to try the trick with the v2.1 you have the installer here:
http://icloud-control-panel-for-windows.uptodown.com/

Remember you need to extract the MSI from the exe to do the trick. After running the exe check the %TEMP% folder to get the MSI file.